# Launchpad .net delays in building package

Tags: launchpad

Are 4 hour wait times for compilation normal? Is there anything I can do to minimize the lag time?

Comment: Could you be more precise as to what you're compiling?

Answer (score 0):

The Launchpad [build farm](https://launchpad.net/builders) is available as a service for free for open source projects to make binaries.

As with all pooled community resources sometimes depending on load this can lead to longer wait times. There's not much you can really do to really reduce the lag, the queues are processes on a first-come-first-served basis.

Comment: Thank you for the infomation, Jorge. Being a newbie, I didn't know if I could select a mirror or the like.